# In 2 John 1:9, is the author equating “both the Father and the Son” with “God”?

Tags: 2-john

In 2 John 1:9, it is written,

> <sup>9</sup> Whoever transgresses and does not abide in the doctrine of Christ does not have God. He who abides in the doctrine of Christ has both the Father and the Son. <sup>NKJV, 1982</sup>
>
> <sup>Θʹ</sup> πᾶς ὁ παραβαίνων καὶ μὴ μένων ἐν τῇ διδαχῇ τοῦ Χριστοῦ, Θεὸν οὐκ ἔχει ὁ μένων ἐν τῇ διδαχῇ τοῦ Χριστοῦ, οὗτος καὶ τὸν πατέρα καὶ τὸν υἱὸν ἔχει  <sup>TR, 1550</sup>

The author makes a factual statement:

- All who do not do A, do not have B.

The inverse of the factual statement would thus be:

- All who do A, do have B.

In the aforementioned statements, **A** represents the action of abiding in the doctrine of Christ, and **B** represents God.

Therefore:

- All who do **not** abide in the doctrine of Christ do **not** have God.
- All who do abide in the doctrine of Christ do have God.

The peculiar aspect of the author’s actual inverse statement is that he does not write, «οὗτος τὸν Θεὸν ἔχει»—“he has God,” as one might expect, but instead he writes, «οὗτος καὶ τὸν πατέρα καὶ τὸν υἱὸν ἔχει»—“he has both the Father and the Son,” thereby effectively substituting «καὶ τὸν πατέρα καὶ τὸν υἱὸν»—“both the Father and the Son”—for «τὸν Θεὸν»—“God.”

**Question**: Is the author indeed equating “**both** the Father and the **Son**” (emphasis on “Son”) with “God”?

Comment: See also John 14:6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simple answer to your question is yes.

Consider Bede's commentary on this passage:

> Note the distinction of words and embrace the truth of faith.  He says
>   that the one who does not remain in the teaching of Christ does not
>   have God, but he says that the one who remains in his teaching has
>   both the Son and the Father, so that he may show that the Father and
>   the Son are the one true God and convict those of lying who maintain
>   that the Son is either not God or posterior or less than the Father.
>
> *Commentary on the Seven Catholic Epistles* (tr. Cistercian Publications, 1985), p. 233

Answer (score 1):

A fine question. The parallelism is obvious and suggests that "the Father and the Son" both stand for the reality of God. In fact, if "father" is God's eternal title and not an adventitious title (like, for instance "creator" is an adventitious title, for God is not necessarily a creator but volitionally, so that in principle He could not be the Creator had He not decided to create the world out of nothing depending on His voluntary decision), then this title necessarily implies also the "son", "offspring", for father is always a father of son (or daughter, or both), that is to say, it analytically implies the offspring as well no less than "wind" analytically implies "blowing" or "water" - "wetness".

Now, "Father" must be God's eternal title, for Jesus addresses Him as Someone who had Him (i.e. Jesus/Logos/Son) before the creation of the world (John 17:5), that is to say, before the world and with it time also began, thus in the eternal realm. Therefore, as Father is eternal, so the Son is co-eternal and eternal Father eternally and analytically implies also eternity and necessity of the Son, and if the shared and identical eternity and necessity, then also shared and identical divinity. That is the full sense of the parallelism of "the Son and the Father" with "God" in 2 John 1:9.

Answer (score -3):

In the letter he speaks about the very perverted ambition of certain people in Jerusalem and about to *let go of the explicit teaching of Jesus* and the teaching of the Twelve ("the apostles' doctrine") and to embrace exaggerated claims about Christ and to "go beyond" what the apostles said and what is written in scripture. The spirit-filled Israel of God value sound doctrine but are intolerant of "docterin'".

John would say that those who name their "Churches" after the "Trinity" have certainly run afoul of this passage because who can produce a single mention of this dogma in scripture? Where do we find ["eternally co-equal with the Father"](https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=father%20is%20greater%20than%20i&t=KJV#s=s_primary_0_1)? Where do we find ["one substance with the Father"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoousion)? This is a perfect example of "going beyond what is written":

> [1Co 4:6 NKJV] 6 Now these things, brethren, I have figuratively transferred to myself and Apollos for your sakes, **that you may learn in us not to think beyond what is written**, that none of you may be puffed up on behalf of one against the other.

Did either Adam or Jesus, both images of God, have three heads?:

[image: Three-headed dragon]

God has one head:

> [1Co 11:3 NKJV] 3 But I want you to know that the head of every man is Christ, the head of woman [is] man, **and the head of Christ [is] God**.

Interestingly, many in Christendom make women equal to her husband, whom she is supposed to call "lord" and they make Christ equal to God though Christ calls him:

- my God and your God:

> [Jhn 20:17 NKJV] 17 Jesus said to her, "Do not cling to Me, for I have not yet ascended to My Father; but go to My brethren and say to them, 'I am ascending to My Father and your Father, and [to] My God and your God.' "

- Father:

> [Luk 22:42 NKJV] 42 saying, "Father, if it is Your will, take this cup away from Me; nevertheless not My will, but Yours, be done."

- the only true God:

> [Jhn 17:3 CSB] 3 "This is eternal life: that they may know **you, the only true God**, and the one you have sent ​-- ​Jesus Christ.

If the same author wrote 3rd John then he says the same there:

> [1Jo 5:10, 20 ASV] 10 He that believeth on the Son of God hath the witness in him: he that believeth not God hath made him a liar; because he hath not believed in the witness that God hath borne concerning his Son. ... 20 And we know that the Son of God is come, and hath given us an understanding, that we know him that is true, and we are in him that is true, [even] in his Son Jesus Christ. This is the true God, and eternal life.

*Note: The bracketed "even" above was added by the translators.*

Of course, I say "three headed" because the question is seeking an affirmation for "the Dogma of the Blessed Trinity" but in reality the poor, neglected Holy Ghost is yet again conspicuously absent from such supposed "[hypostases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostases)", and no one even notices!

To understand this text by other texts within scripture (rather than from dogma) I turn to the words of Christ:

> [Jhn 14:6 KJV] 6 Jesus saith unto him, I am the way [to God], the truth [about God], and the life: no man cometh unto the Father, but by me.
>
> [Jhn 11:25 KJV] 25 Jesus said unto her, I am the resurrection, and the life: **he that believeth in me, though he were dead, yet shall he live**:

Ah, so wonderful and simple! So why do people want to pass this by in favor of this kind of drivel?:

> Creed of Athanasius
>
> 1. Whosoever will be saved, before all things it is necessary that he hold the catholic faith;
> 2. Which faith except every one do keep whole and undefiled, without doubt he shall perish everlastingly.
> 3. And the catholic faith is this: That we worship one God in Trinity, and Trinity in Unity;
> 4. Neither confounding the persons nor dividing the substance.
> 5. For there is one person of the Father, another of the Son, and another of the Holy Spirit.
> 6. But the Godhead of the Father, of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit is all one, the glory equal, the majesty coeternal.
> 7. Such as the Father is, such is the Son, and such is the Holy Spirit.
> 8. The Father uncreated, the Son uncreated, and the Holy Spirit uncreated.
> 9. The Father incomprehensible, the Son incomprehensible, and the Holy Spirit incomprehensible.
> 10. The Father eternal, the Son eternal, and the Holy Spirit eternal.
> 11. And yet they are not three eternals but one eternal.
> 12. As also there are not three uncreated nor three incomprehensible, but one uncreated and one incomprehensible.
> 13. So likewise the Father is almighty, the Son almighty, and the Holy Spirit almighty.
> 14. And yet they are not three almighties, but one almighty.
> 15. So the Father is God, the Son is God, and the Holy Spirit is God;
> 16. And yet they are not three Gods, but one God.
> 17. So likewise the Father is Lord, the Son Lord, and the Holy Spirit Lord;
> 18. And yet they are not three Lords but one Lord.
> 19. For like as we are compelled by the Christian verity to acknowledge every Person by himself to be God and Lord;
> 20. So are we forbidden by the catholic religion to say; There are three Gods or three Lords.
> 21. The Father is made of none, neither created nor begotten.
> 22. The Son is of the Father alone; not made nor created, but begotten.
> 23. The Holy Spirit is of the Father and of the Son; neither made, nor created, nor begotten, but proceeding.
> 24. So there is one Father, not three Fathers; one Son, not three Sons; one Holy Spirit, not three Holy Spirits.
> 25. And in this Trinity none is afore or after another; none is greater or less than another.
> 26. But the whole three persons are coeternal, and coequal.
> 27. So that in all things, as aforesaid, the Unity in Trinity and the Trinity in Unity is to be worshipped.
> 28. He therefore that will be saved must thus think of the Trinity.
> 29. Furthermore it is necessary to everlasting salvation that he also believe rightly the incarnation of our Lord Jesus Christ.
> 30. For the right faith is that we believe and confess that our Lord Jesus Christ, the Son of God, is God and man.
> 31. God of the substance of the Father, begotten before the worlds; and man of substance of His mother, born in the world.
> 32. Perfect God and perfect man, of a reasonable soul and human flesh subsisting.
> 33. Equal to the Father as touching His Godhead, and inferior to the Father as touching His manhood.
> 34. Who, although He is God and man, yet He is not two, but one Christ.
> 35. One, not by conversion of the Godhead into flesh, but by taking of that manhood into God.
> 36. One altogether, not by confusion of substance, but by unity of person.
> 37. For as the reasonable soul and flesh is one man, so God and man is one Christ;
> 38. Who suffered for our salvation, descended into hell, rose again the third day from the dead;
> 39. He ascended into heaven, He sits on the right hand of the Father, God, Almighty;
> 40. From thence He shall come to judge the quick and the dead.
> 41. At whose coming all men shall rise again with their bodies;
> 42. and shall give account of their own works.
> 43. And they that have done good shall go into life everlasting and they that have done evil into everlasting fire.
> 44. This is the catholic faith, which except a man believe faithfully he cannot be saved.

To those who think, "That's just scripture rephrased" I challenge you to find a scriptural reference that makes the same assertion as any of these 40 assertions except for the most benign (IE: Yes, there is but one God).

Surely in the last days of the old covenant and the first days of the new one can find no fellowship with God while rejecting the messiah! Here Jesus says that he and his Father are numerically two witnesses in perfect agreement:

> [Jhn 8:17-19 KJV] 17  It is also written in your law, that the testimony of two men is true. 18 I am one that bear witness of myself, and the Father that sent me beareth witness of me. 19 Then said they unto him, Where is thy Father? Jesus answered, Ye neither know me, nor my Father: if ye had known me, ye should have known my Father also.

I must say it is a shame to see so much effort to prop up the Roman Catholic lie. And not just any lie, but THE lie:

> [2Th 2:3-12 KJV] 3 Let no man deceive you by any means: for [that day shall not come], except there come a falling away first, and that man of sin be revealed, the son of perdition; 4 **Who opposeth and exalteth himself above all that is called God, or that is worshipped; so that he as God sitteth in the temple of God, shewing himself that he is God. 5 Remember ye not, that, when I was yet with you, I told you these things?** 6 And now ye know what withholdeth that he might be revealed in his time. 7 For the mystery of iniquity doth already work: only he who now letteth [will let], until he be taken out of the way. 8 And then shall that Wicked be revealed, whom the Lord shall consume with the spirit of his mouth, and shall destroy with the brightness of his coming: 9 [Even him], whose coming is after the working of Satan with all power and signs and lying wonders, 10 And with all deceivableness of unrighteousness in them that perish; because they received not the love of the truth, that they might be saved. 11 And for this cause God shall send them strong delusion, that they should believe a lie: 12 That they all might be damned who believed not the truth, but had pleasure in unrighteousness.

The purpose of the verse was to insist that the godly woman hosting traveling teachers (or possibly, the "elect lady" is an assembly) that she/they must not be host to teachers that "make up stuff" about Christ. If it isn't in the scriptures and they teach it, send them away from your door.

> [1Co 8:6 KJV] 6 But to us [there is but] one God, the Father, of whom [are] all things, and we in him; and one Lord Jesus Christ, by whom [are] all things, and we by him.

---

When the Binitarian dogma was first created (because the two-headed god was invented before the three-headed one) the vast majority of bishops attempted to reject it but in the end the Roman Church had his way. It still does today. Few dare even to consider violating the creed!